Are Metric Balls on a Riemannian Manifold Embedded Submanifolds?
Let $(M,g)$ be a connected $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. We can define a topological metric on $M$ by
$$ d_g(p,q) = \inf\{\text{Length}(\gamma) \mid \gamma \ \text{is a piecewise smooth curve from $p$ to $q$}\}.$$
Consider the closed ball of radius $R$ centred at $p \in M$, denoted $B_R(p)$. Is this an $n$-dimensional embedded submanifold with boundary of $M$?
My thoughts:
If $R$ is less than the injectivity radius at $p$, the answer is yes because the metric ball will coincide with the geodesic ball, which is diffeomorphic to the standard closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
For $R$ larger or equal to the injectivity radius at $p$ I am not so sure anymore.
I would be grateful for any help!

You should replace "submanifold" with "submanifold with boundary." In any case, the answer is negative already in dimension 2. I suggest you think about the case when $(M,g)$ is a cylinder.

@MoisheKohan if I understand correctly, in the case of the cylinder (say of radius 1), in Euclidean space it could happen (e.g. if $R=\pi$) that a „rolled up“ disk where two antipodal points are touching is the resulting metric ball? This is clearly not a manifold at all.

Right. You can now write your own answer and accept it.

The comment of Moishe Kohan was very enlightening in that he gave a hint towards a counter example:
In the case of the cylinder (say of radius 1) in Euclidean space it could happen (e.g. if $R=\pi$) that a „rolled up“ disk where two antipodal points are touching is the resulting metric ball. This is clearly not a manifold at all.
